# Installing a local library in react js project

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a project in reactjs using create-react-App and someone provided me the local library to install in my project to have a common component which we are sharing. This library is built on create-react-library.

When I am installing it, everything's working except my test cases. Here's the error.

```
23 | function _interopDefault (ex) { return (ex && (typeof ex === 'object') && 'default' in ex) ? ex['default'] : ex; }
  24 |
> 25 | var React = require('react');
     |             ^
  26 | var React__default = _interopDefault(React);
  27 | var officeUiFabricReact = require('office-ui-fabric-react');
```

And my package.json

```
{
"name": "presaletodelivery",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@uifabric/styling": "^7.12.16",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "country-state-city": "^1.0.5",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "fetch-mock": "^7.3.9",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^11.0.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.115.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-avatar-uploader": "^1.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-api-middleware": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.0",
    "jest-junit": "^6.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "local-lib": "../local-lib"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage"
}
"jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "!coverage/**",
    "!ptdui/node_modules/**",
    "!src/index.js",
    "!src/setupTests.js",
    "!src/index.test.js",
    "!src/App.test.js",
    "!src/serviceWorker.js",
    "!public/**",
    "!build/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
    "text",
    "lcov",
    "json",
    "text",
    "clover"
    ]
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all",
    "ie >= 9"
    ],
    "development": [
    "ie >= 9",
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

Have anyone faced this issue before.

Comment: in which file does this error happen? and how did you install this library - with npm or copy-paste?

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk This library is sbling of my project. Adding it in package json file with this code "local-lib": "../local-lib"

Comment: Please also supply the message of the error. I assume it says something like : `require is not defined`
this is most likely because the local-lib package was built with webpack, and you're using the resulting bundled javascipt code.
Bundled js code is not made to be a library, it is made to be loaded by the browser. In your project you need an actual source code to be  in `node_modules` folder.